# Masking an inherited class in python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have a series of objects representing (recurring) events in my code. Part of what I'm doing involves working out when these recurrences happen, and returning a list of the dates.

To do this, I've written a helper class which takes the original event and also the updated start and finish dates

```
class repeat():
    def __init__(self, event, start=None, finish=None):
        self.event = event
        self.start = start if start is not None else event.start
        self.finish = finish if finish is not None else event.finish
```

I'd like to directly access the `event` elements from the `repeat` class, i.e.:

```
>>> e = event(args)
>>> e.summary()
"Meeting with Sally"
>>> R = repeat(event)
>>> R.summary()
"Meeting with Sally"
```

In this example, the `summary()` function belongs to the `event` instance `e` and not `R`, so you don't have to call `R.event.summary()`. Is this possible?

I've tried googling it, but I don't know what this is called, so I haven't had much luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fake/proxy a class in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942536/how-to-fake-proxy-a-class-in-python)

Comment: You sure you want a `repeat` class for this, rather than just making a new regular event with different start and finish times? What should happen if you call `repeat` on a `repeat` instance?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I was thinking that a "wrapper" class might be better, so that if the original data was changed, it would reflect in the repeated events. It's probably mostly academic, though, as the list of repeated events is really only going to be used and then discarded.