# Subclass that catches all exceptions from superclass

Tags: python, exception

For example, I have a `Robot` class, but instead of catching exceptions manually when I'm doing something with a robot instance, I want to wrap the `Robot` class in a `LoggingRobot` class that catches any exceptions `Robot`'s methods might throw and uses the `logging` module to report them.

Is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fake/proxy a class in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942536/how-to-fake-proxy-a-class-in-python)

Comment: Essentially, you proxy the underlying class and wrap all of the proxy accessors in a `try-except` block that logs the exception and then re-raises it.

Comment: Note that simply logging exceptions is almost always not sufficient to actually *deal* with them. Hence why you re-raise after trapping.