# Why magic methods are not intercepted by __getattr__ implementation in python?

Tags: python, indexing, containers, magic-methods, getattr

Subj.

Example:

```
MyList(object):

    def __init__(self, list_to_be_wrapped):
          self._items = list_to_be_wrapped

    def __getattr__(self, item):
          return getattr(self._items, item)
```

Then

```
MyList([1, 2, 3])[-1]
```

will raise:  `TypeError: ‘MyList’ object does not support indexing`

while:

```
MyList([1, 2, 3]).pop()
```

will work perfectly (`pop` will be intercepted by the `__getattr__` and redirected to `_items`)

It seems for me that interception of magic methods by `__getattr__` would be very helpful considering the case of "implementing own container types via composition not inheritance". Why is such "interception" not supported in python?

Comment: __getitem__ is used under the hood when calling indexes on objects.     `def __getitem__(self, y): 
        """ x.__getitem__(y) <==> x[y] """`

Comment: I think the OP's question is why magic methods aren't redirected to `__getattr__`. In other words, why is `obj[x]` not equivalent to `obj.__getattr__("__getitem__")(x)`. To the OP: If that were the case, it would imply that `__getattr__` would have to be sent to itself ;)

Comment: @CeasarBautista Indeed it does, see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the full answer, you need to look at the [documentation for special method lookup](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-special-lookup), specifically:

> In addition to bypassing any instance attributes in the interest of
>   correctness, implicit special method lookup generally also bypasses
>   the [`__getattribute__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) method even of the object’s metaclass.

Which is justified by:

> Bypassing the `__getattribute__()` machinery in this fashion provides
>   significant scope for speed optimisations within the interpreter, at
>   the cost of some flexibility in the handling of special methods (the
>   special method must be set on the class object itself in order to be
>   consistently invoked by the interpreter).

Note that this only applies for new-style classes (classes which extend `object`), but you really should always use new-style classes for any new code.

The simplest solution is that you need to manually proxy all of the special methods you wish to redirect to the proxy'd class.

Comment: It's interesting to note that this only applies to new-style classes. If you don't subclass from `object`, OP's code actually works.

Comment: @aruisdante, Thank you for advice to "manually proxy all..." ... Currently I am looking how to "automate" thise proxying... Something like the following: `setattr(self, '__getitem__', lambda *args: getattr(self._items, '__getitem__')(*args))` inside `__init__` method does not work... Is there any way to achieve what i want? What did I wrong in my solution?

Comment: @yashaka [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496741-object-proxying/) is a really good recipe for general object proxying in Python, as well as a good SO QA on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942536/how-to-fake-proxy-a-class-in-python. The recipe shows you about the limit to how much you can automate the proxying facilities.