# Delegate to a dict class in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, delegates

In Python 3, I have a tree of lists and dicts that I get from another library. I'd like to instrument the dicts in that tree with objects containing more behavior (giving a richer model to the simple dict classes). I've tried replacing the class of these objects with a subclass of dict, but that is not allowed:

```
class MyClass(dict): pass
{}.__class__ = MyClass
```

That fails with `TypeError: __class__ assignment: only for heap types`.

So I'm instead trying to write a wrapper or adapter or delegate class:

```
class InstrumentedDict(object):
    """
    Instrument an existing dictionary with additional
    functionality, but always reference and mutate
    the original dictionary.

    >>> orig = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
    >>> inst = InstrumentedDict(orig)
    >>> hasattr(inst, '__getitem__')
    True
    >>> inst.__getitem__('a')
    1
    >>> inst['a']
    1
    >>> inst['c'] = 3
    >>> orig['c']
    3
    >>> inst.keys() == orig.keys()
    True
    """
    def __init__(self, orig):
        self._orig = orig

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        orig = super(InstrumentedDict, self).__getattribute__('_orig')
        return orig.__getattribute__(name)
```

However, the doctests fail at `inst['a']` with `TypeError: 'InstrumentedDict' object is not subscriptable`. Note, however, that it doesn't fail to invoke `__hasattr__` or `__getitem__`.

I'm hoping to delegate all behavior to the underlying dictionary, and I'd like not to have to think about or explicitly delegate the whole signature of a dictionary.

It's important that whatever this class does should affect the underlying dict (rather than creating separate references to the values). Ideally, it should not impose or negate mutability on the underlying Mapping, but should mirror its behavior.

Is there a simple and elegant solution that meets the specified interface but doesn't require explicit mirroring of the signature (such as in [this implementation](https://bitbucket.org/jaraco/jaraco.collections/src/0c86678fd275b216bc1b0e41be7fc952ca7cf727/jaraco/collections.py?at=default#cl-742))?

**Edit:** To clarify, I want to overlay behavior on existing dictionaries without creating new copies, such that if the instrumented copy is modified, so is the original.

Comment: I don't see a `__getitem__`.... or a `__setitem__`...

Comment: The difference between `inst.__getitem__('a')` and `inst['a']` is that the latter will always search for actual `__getitem__` in the class(considering you're using a new style class).

Comment: You may need to implement something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942536/how-to-fake-proxy-a-class-in-python if you want a really authentic proxy...

Comment: I'll add `object`, and clarify that I'm testing on Python 3.

Comment: This strikes me as an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  Why not just subclass `dict` and replace the specific methods that you wish to enrich.

Comment: @dawg, I added an edit to the question to more explicitly describe my intention - to instrument dict objects that I get from another library, but I want to avoid creating copies, which a dict subclass necessarily does because a dict object has its own intrinsic storage.

Comment: @dawg: Perhaps you're right about the XY Problem. I started with the assumption laid out in the question - that I have a library supplying a tree of dict objects. I want to augment those dictionaries with behavior without the expense of reconstructing that tree with new objects. I've found the answer I was seeking, but I'll consider a follow-up question to the broader problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a risk of completely missing the point of your question...

Is there any reason to build a proxy instead of just subclassing `dict`? Something like:

```
class InstrumentedDict(dict):
    """ Walks like a dict, talks like a dict... """
```

---

**Edit after comment:**

Ah, I see :)  Makes sense...

Seems like `UserDict` is the answer, check this out:

```
from collections import UserDict

class InstrumentedDict(UserDict):

    def __init__(self, data):
        super(InstrumentedDict, self).__init__()
        self.data = data

remote_dict = {"a": 1}
instr_dict = InstrumentedDict(remote_dict)

print(instr_dict)  # {'a': 1}

instr_dict["b"] = 2

print(instr_dict)  # {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
print(remote_dict)  # {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

`UserDict` seems to be a relic from olden days when we couldn't subclass `dict` directly. But it's useful because it exposes `data` attribute. And that's pretty much all what the docs say: [UserDict](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#userdict-objects)

Comment: Right - because I can't use that InstrumentedDict to overlay an existing dict. It will make a copy when the source dict is passed in. It's important that the original dictionary is mutated with the proxy.

Comment: @frnhr That works beautifully. I had overlooked UserDict because my impression of it was that it was obviated by subclassing dict, but as you've now demonstrated, here's one case where UserDict provides flexibility that subclassing a dict cannot.