# Proxy class can't call methods on child

Tags: python, class, proxy

I'm writing a Python class to wrap/decorate/enhance another class from a package called [petl](https://github.com/alimanfoo/petl), a framework for ETL (data movement) workflows. Due to design constraints I can't just subclass it; every method call has to be sent through my own class so I can control what kind of objects are being passed back. So in principle this is a proxy class, but I'm having some trouble using existing answers/recipes out there. This is what my code looks like:

```
from functools import partial

class PetlTable(object):
    """not really how we construct petl tables, but for illustrative purposes"""
    def hello(name):
        print('Hello, {}!'.format(name)

class DatumTable(object):
    def __init__(self, petl_tbl):
        self.petl_tbl = petl_tbl

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """this returns a partial referencing the child method"""

        petl_attr = getattr(self.petl_tbl, name, None)

        if petl_attr and callable(petl_attr):
            return partial(self.call_petl_method, func=petl_attr)

        raise NotImplementedError('Not implemented')

    def call_petl_method(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then I try to instantiate a table and call something:

```
# create a petl table
pt = PetlTable()

# wrap it with our own class
dt = DatumTable(pt)

# try to run the petl method
dt.hello('world')
```

This gives a `TypeError: call_petl_method() got multiple values for argument 'func'`.

This only happens with positional arguments; kwargs seem to be fine. I'm pretty sure it has to do with `self` not being passed in, but I'm not sure what the solution is. Can anyone think of what I'm doing wrong, or a better solution altogether?

Comment: Would be helpful to know exactly what `petl` is as well as what `petl.fromcsv('test.csv')` returns—neither is defined in the code shown in your question.

Comment: there is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942536/how-to-fake-proxy-a-class-in-python) question which contains a link to an activestate recipe. Might be a useful alternative.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the question with more info on what the library is and what it returns, however I just wanted to point out that this isn't really specific to `petl`. It's just a pass-through to another class, which could be anything.

Comment: Then I suggest that you [edit] your question and add another class and some code that demonstrates the problem (using it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a common issue with mixing positional and keyword args:
[TypeError: got multiple values for argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764770/typeerror-got-multiple-values-for-argument)

To get around it, I took the positional arg `func` out of `call_petl_method` and put it in a kwarg that's unlikely to overlap with the kwargs of the child function. A little hacky, but it works.

I ended up writing a `Proxy` class to do all this generically:

```
class Proxy(object):
    def __init__(self, child):
        self.child = child

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        child_attr = getattr(self.child, name)
        return partial(self.call_child_method, __child_fn__=child_attr)

    @classmethod
    def call_child_method(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        This calls a method on the child object and wraps the response as an
        object of its own class.

        Takes a kwarg `__child_fn__` which points to a method on the child
        object.

        Note: this can't take any positional args or they get clobbered by the
        keyword args we're trying to pass to the child. See:
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764770/typeerror-got-multiple-values-for-argument
        """

        # get child method
        fn = kwargs.pop('__child_fn__')

        # call the child method
        r = fn(*args, **kwargs)

        # wrap the response as an object of the same class
        r_wrapped = cls(r)

        return r_wrapped
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also solve the problem. It doesn't use `partial` at all.

```
class PetlTable(object):
    """not really how we construct petl tables, but for illustrative purposes"""
    def hello(name):
        print('Hello, {}!'.format(name))

class DatumTable(object):
    def __init__(self, petl_tbl):
        self.petl_tbl = petl_tbl

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """Looks-up named attribute in class of the petl_tbl object."""

        petl_attr = self.petl_tbl.__class__.__dict__.get(name, None)

        if petl_attr and callable(petl_attr):
            return petl_attr

        raise NotImplementedError('Not implemented')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create a petl table
    pt = PetlTable()

    # wrap it with our own class
    dt = DatumTable(pt)

    # try to run the petl method
    dt.hello('world')  # -> Hello, world!
```