# Python: Wrapper class that emulates the wrapped class function calls

Tags: python

I'd like to create a class that will be a wrapper to another class, and maintain information about the execution of the wrapped class. For example, I want to monitor the number of times each method in the wrapped class was called. However I want the wrapper to feel just like the wrapped class.

To do that, I want that the line `wrapper.foo(arg1="value1", arg2="value2")` will call:

```
def execute(self, function_name, args):
    # function_name = "foo"
    # args = {"arg1": "value1", "arg2": "value2"}

    self.call_counter[function_name] += 1
    return getattr(self.wrapped_class, function_name)(**args)
```

I was hoping that somehow `__getattr__` would work, but that doesn't work if I want to pass arguments as well.

How can I implement that transparent wrapper effect?

Comment: So what should happen when you do `func = wrapper.foo`, then later on you do `func(arg1="value1", arg2="value2)`? That's the difficulty here, looking up a method and actually calling it are *two separate expressions*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's true, and I suppose there's no solution to something like that, but at least in my case it wouldn't be an issue. I just want to add to my code a way to conveniently monitor class usage, and in case I remove the wrapper, the code using the wrapped class remains the same.

Comment: Well, there is; you'd have to return a wrapper from the `__getattr__` method, something that *when called* will increment the call counter and pass the call through to the original method. It's deciding when to use the wrapper that is trickier. Should all callable objects be wrapped (methods are not the only things that are callable)? What if the attribute is both callable and supports other actions, should those be proxied too?

Comment: Why not just override the class methods within the wrapper and inside do whatever you want beside calling to the parent method?

Comment: Using the `Proxy` pattern, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942536/how-to-fake-proxy-a-class-in-python) and [here](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Fronting.html)