# Python inherit magic methods based off __init__ value

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's imagine I have a **single** class `X`. The purpose of `X` is to wrap a `list` or `dict` and provide event-listening capabilities. All works well.

```
class X(object):
    def __init__(self, obj)
        self._obj = obj

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # do stuff with self._obj

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._obj[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        self._obj[key] = val

    # rest of functionality ...
```

So this can be used to wrap a `dict` like so:

```
x = X({
    'foo' : False
})

x.listen('foo', callback)

X['foo'] = True         # triggers event
X.update({
    'foo' : False       # triggers event
})
```

Or a `list`:

```
x = X([1,2])

x.listen(callback)

X.append(1)        # triggers event
X[0] = 10          # triggers event
```

Great. Almost to what I wanted to accomplish ...

Now the current issue is that, because `X` is for both `list` and `dict` objects, it can't inherit from either. This means I don't have the magic class functions, such as `__contains__`.

Which leads code like this

```
d = X({
        'foo' : True    
    })

    if 'foo' in d:
        print 'yahoo!'
```

Throwing a `KeyError`.

How can I work around this without defining every magic method I need inside of `X`. If I did it this way, for each of those definitions I would have to write two return values based off whether `self._obj` is a `list` or `dict`.

I thought I could do this with metaclasses at first but that doesn't seem to be a solution, since I need access to the values being passed to check whether it's a `dict` or `list`.

Comment: Are you sure you need capabilities for both list and dict in your program? This sounds like a great place to split into two classes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942536/how-to-fake-proxy-a-class-in-python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091833/proxy-object-in-python

Comment: @JoshLee Those don't address special methods.

Comment: Perhaps this approach will work? [How can I intercept calls to python's “magic” methods in new style classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057669/how-can-i-intercept-calls-to-pythons-magic-methods-in-new-style-classes).  The example `DictWrapper` includes a test of `__contains__`

Comment: @jq170727 Sure, I thought about that approach but I am being a bit picky in the sense that I don't want to have to call `x = XDict({})` or `x = XList([])`. I just want to call `X({})` or `X([])` to keep things simple for the end user. Especially in the future if I decide to extend this event-listener to user-defined objects like classes.

Comment: What good would it do for your `X` to inherit from `list` or `dict` since you want to wrap an existing object?

Comment: @DavisHerring I need to inherit the special/magic methods from `list` or `dict` depending on the case, because I need the special methods like I provided in my question. I can't intercept magic method calls, so I need to have them added to the class dynamically before it is initalized.

Comment: If you _inherit_ them, they will access `self` rather than (the desired) `self._obj`.

Comment: Why does `X` have to be a class?  If `X` were a function it could inspect the type of `obj` and dynamically return the appropriate wrapper instance.

Comment: @DavisHerring You can't inherit a both a `list` and `dict` in the same class.

Comment: I do know about that restriction.  I meant that inheriting from `list` _or_ `dict` would not have the desired effect in this case (even for one type to be wrapped).

Comment: Is there a reason that this has to be both a list and dict? what do you get from one that you can't get from the other? You could just build one lightweight class `X()` that looks at what you pass into `__init__(self,obj):` and looks at obj returning a private type of the object you want that defines the same behavior you need. We had a "similar" situation where we were doing some stuff in Couchbase for events and we abandoned Lists/Array's and "engineered" Dicts/Maps to behave similarly.

Comment: Magic methods are only looked up on the class, not the instance.  There is no way to dynamically select a magic method per instance.  Just define all the magic methods on your class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy way would be to use a proxy class, for example [`wrapt.ObjectProxy`](http://wrapt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wrappers.html#proxies-and-wrappers). It will behave exactly like the "proxied" class except for the overridden methods. However instead of `self._obj` you can simply use `self.__wrapped__` to access the "unproxied" object.

```
from wrapt import ObjectProxy

class Wrapper(ObjectProxy):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print('getattr')
        return getattr(self.__wrapped__, name)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print('getitem')
        return self.__wrapped__[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        print('setitem')
        self.__wrapped__[key] = val

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.__wrapped__)
```

This behaves like a dict if you wrap a dict:

```
>>> d = Wrapper({'foo': 10})
>>> d['foo']
getitem
10
>>> 'foo' in d   # "inherits" __contains__
True
```

and like a list, if a list is wrapped:

```
>>> d = Wrapper([1,2,3])
>>> d[0]
getitem
1
>>> for i in d:   # "inherits" __iter__
...     print(i)
1
2
3
```

Comment: All `wrapt.ObjectProxy` does is provide all the special methods and attributes (the latter as `property` objects) and just proxy those to the wrapped object. So `def __contains__(self, value): return self.__wrapped__.__contains__(value)`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `UserList` or `UserDict` from [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList)

```
from collections import UserList


class X(UserList):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = obj

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        pass
        # do stuff with self.data

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        self.data[key] = val


x0 = X([1, 2, 3])
x1 = X({1, 2, 3})
x2 = X({1: 1, 2: 2})

print(1 in x0)
print(1 in x1)
print(1 in x2)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try something like

```
def contains (self, item):
    If isinstance (self._obj, list):
        return list.contains (self._obj, item)
    If isinstance (self._obj, dict):
        return dict.contains (self._obj, item)
```

Or what ever method it is you want to inherit. When an instance method is called, the instance is auto-passed with self. But if you call the method from the class decleration you need to pass an object because self requires a value.

```
Class Test:
    def print_cls (self):
        print self.__class__.__name__


t = Test ()

t.print_cls () # self is teat

Test.print_cls (5) 
# we replace self with another class object
# as long as the object you pass has the
# variables used in the method you call all should be good.
```

This will print out `Test` and `int`

Comment: It looks like the goal is that an instance of `X` will look exactly like whatever object was passed to it, not that you have to call some special function like `contains()` rather than using the `in` operator. You also wouldn't want to special case particular classes like `list` and `dict`. I'm not sure what your snippet with the `Test` class is about, but it clearly doesn't have much to do with the question.